# Comparing a DATETIME2 column to a DATETIME2 field does not return expected results

Tags: azure-sql-database

When tracking down a deadlock and I noticed that when I looks for records that occurred this morning that nothing is returned. However, if I looks for records that occurred **before** `1/1/1900`, then records with a time **after** `6/30/2020 15:00` are returned. This is using SQL Server Azure PaaS.

`[timestamp_utc]` is a `DateTime2`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, when we run the script, Azure SQL server backend may not recognize the filed `timestamp_utc` as `DateTime2` type. So we need to convert it  to `DateTime2` type manually.

For example

```
SELECT  timestamp_utc
FROM sys.fn_xe_telemetry_blob_target_read_file('dl', null, null, null)
WHERE CAST(timestamp_utc AS datetime2) > '2019-03-25 10:20:00'
```

[image]

Comment: Well, that did it. I also left feedback with Microsoft about this.